# How do I assign a value to a property where the property name is supplied at runtime in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a worksheet that creates a list of values that will be used to initialize the values of an instantiated class.

For example, I might have the following in my initialization worksheet:

```
Property Name              Value
StartingCol                A
StartingRow                11
```

I'd then create a class that would parse this worksheet and provide me with an enumberable that I could use to initialize the properties of an instantiated object.  However, I'm not sure how I might be able to specify the property value at runtime using a string rather than specifying it explicitly in code.  You can get an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish in the code below:

```
Sub test_PropertyAssignment()
Dim sp As SheetParser
Dim strFieldName As String
Dim strFieldNameValue As String
Set sp = New SheetParser

'The property name is supplied explicitly'
sp.StartingCol = "B"

strFieldName = "StartingCol"
strFieldNameValue = "B"

sp.[how can I supply strFieldName to specify the property?] = strFieldNameValue 'Will not Work'

End Sub
```

Is there a way to use a string at runtime to specify the property name rather than specifying explicitly in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up the `CallByName` function in the VBA help.
You should be able to do something like:

```
Call CallByName(sp,strFieldName,vbLet,strFieldNameValue)
```

Comment: This worked great for Let property assignments.  Now I'm trying to figure out how to make it work for Set properties on objects that haven't been instantiated yet.  Another SO question.

Comment: You definitely need an actual object instance to use CallByName().