# How to dynamically reference an object property in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, object

I'm trying to write a VBA function that counts the objects in a collection based on the value of one of the object's properties. I need the examined object property to be dynamic, supplied by the function parameters. I could use an `if then` statement, but that would have many, many `elseif` clauses, each with identical procedures, except the property name.

I'd like to avoid repeating my code over and over for each property name. Here's what I have so far.

```
Private Function getTicketCount(c As Collection, f As String, s As String) _
 As Long
' @param c: collection of Ticket objects.
' @param f: property to filter.
' @param s: filter string.
'
' Function returns number of tickets that pass the filter.

Dim x As Long
Dim t As Ticket

x = 0

For Each t In c
    If t.f = s Then x = x + 1 ' Compiler throws "Method or data member not found."
Next t

getTicketCount = x
End Function
```

The issue I'm having is that the compiler is looking for the "f" property of t instead of the value-of-f property of t. The exact error is commented in the code block above. How do I use the value of f instead of "f" to reference the object property?

Comment: How many properties does `Ticket` have?  It's not elegant, but you could do `Select Case f` and have the cases be the different properties.

Comment: What exactly is the error that you are getting?

Comment: Question edited to clarify. The compiler throws an error, because it's looking for property "f" when it _should_ be looking for property value-of-f. The passed property string does exist. The object itself has a few dozen properties, and coding them all under separate case clauses is precisely what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you want to use the CallByName method [CallByName MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22x2chfx.aspx)

```
Private Function getTicketCount(c As Collection, f As String, s As String) _
 As Long
' @param c: collection of Ticket objects.
' @param f: property to filter.
' @param s: filter string.
'
' Function returns number of tickets that pass the filter.

Dim x As Long
Dim t As Ticket

x = 0

For Each t In c
    If CallByName(t, f, VbGet) = s Then x = x + 1 ' Compiler throws "Method or data member not found."
Next t

getTicketCount = x
End Function
```

Comment: Yes! I was looking for just such a function on MSDN, but couldn't find it. Thank you!

Comment: This answer also shows how to set the property with CallByName.  The documentation isn't entirely clear on that, particularly on when to use vbSet vs vbLet.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706791/how-do-i-use-variables-to-set-properties-in-vba-excel

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem and get a Type mismatch for SCHED_ANAL, which is a public array used to store numerous values for project schedule quality calculations.  I have a set of functions that compute quality based on several parameters.  Basic code is as follows:

'
' Declared in a module
'
Public SCHED_ANAL(NoAnalItems) As SA_Array ' SA_Array is custom with 35 items

Function qsM (stype)
' stype is the type of calculation to perform (e.g., "SAT")

dim qa as single

qa=CallByName(SCHED_ANAL(PMDurn),stype,VbGet)
...
End Function

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).