# Set Class property using Sub

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a `Sub` which will take a value and a `Class` `Property` and set the `Property` for me.

In my `Class` (`Class1`) I have the following:

```
Option Explicit

Private vValue As String, vTest As String
Public Property Let Value(v As String)
    vValue = v
End Property
Public Property Get Value() As String
    Value = vValue
End Property
Public Property Let Test(v As String)
    vTest = v
End Property
Public Property Get Test() As String
    Test = vTest
End Property
```

Then I am calling it using the following `Sub` in `Module1`

```
Sub TestSetProperty()
    Dim cl As New Class1

    SetProperty "Test", cl.Value

    Debug.Print "Value:", cl.Value
    Debug.Print "Test:", cl.Test

End Sub
```

My `SetProperty` `Sub` contains

```
Sub SetProperty(v As String, ByRef prop)
    prop = v
End Sub
```

Now I'd expect this to pass the property to the `SetProperty` `Sub` and set the value giving:

```
Value:        Test
Test:
```

in the immediate window, however instead it returns

```
Value:        
Test:
```

How can I make this work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted is trying to pass a method by reference.  This is not possible in VBA.  The closest you can get is the CallByName function

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/user-interface-help/callbyname-function

Comment: And here is a link showing some [sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5707956/5162073).

Comment: `to pass a method by reference` - property, that is. They did [implement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/564564/11683) it in VB.NET. This answer is correct for VBA though.

Comment: That's quite disappointing but thank you for the alternative - will accept it as answered

Comment: Was there a reason you were not able to use cl.Test=cl.Value