# How to use String value as a dot operation in VBA? it is possible?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub getTrailInfo()
    Dim attr As Variant
    Dim attrTB As String
    attrNames = Split("trailName,trailType,aSideSite,zSideSite,status", ",")
    Dim trailForm As New formTrailInfo
        For Each attr In attrNames
            attrTB = attr + "TB"
             trailForm.attrTB = attr
        Next attr

        trailForm.Show
End Sub
```

When I run the above code it gives a compilor error: Method or Data not found at line `trailForm.attrTB = attr`

I have required variables in attrNames String array. I need to put values of these variables in corosponding textboxes in a userForm. The name of Text Box in this userForm is attrNameTB. For example Text box for trailName is trailNameTB.

Comment: With your intelliSense turned on, you should see the name of the textboxes after you type the dot. attrNameTB should show when this is a textbox on your form. Another hint is to start debugging and use watches...

Comment: Not sure if you are trying `trailForm.Controls(attrTB).Text = attr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use VBA like that.

When you start your code, the compiler will *first* compile the code and check that you want to access a property named `attrTB` of your form. This doesn't exist and you will get the error you mentioned.

The compiler cannot wait until your variable `attrTB` has an actual value and then guess that you don't want a property with that name, but use the content of that variable as property name.

However, every form has a collection of all it's controls (button, edit boxes, combo boxes, labels...), and you can access the members of a collection either by index or by name. As you have the name of the control in `attrTB`, you could simply write

```
trailForm.Controls(attrTB).Text = attr
```

Comment: `You cannot use VBA like that` - until you [can](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5706791/11683) ;)

Comment: I like to play with such attempts - for fun. But I cannot think about a real use of that...

Comment: Thank you Thomas, I am not sure if it is possible but can I somehow use the string value stored in attr as a variable? So attr is actually a varibale Name as a String. Example attr = "trailName" and trailName = "actualTrailName". Can I somehow get "actualTrailName" from attr?  I don't know much about VBA just trying to automate some of my work. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @LakshaySharma It is here a variable as string.

Comment: @GSerg Yes attr is a String with a varibale name

Comment: I figured it out, I just saved all the variables in a Dictionary and used the following line of code. trailForm.Controls(attrTB).Value = Ats(attr) where Ats is a dictionary with all the variables and their values. Thanks alot guys