# How do I create a new form instance whose name I have in a string?

Tags: vba, ms-access

In MS Access, there are two ways to open a new form:

1. `DoCmd.OpenForm "myForm"` - opens the "default instance" of a form
2. `Set frm = New Form_myForm : frm.Visible = True` - opens a *new* instance of a form.

I need to use the second option, because I want to open multiple instances of `myForm`. (If you are unfamiliar with it, more details about this technique can be found [here](http://www.allenbrowne.com/ser-35.html).)

How would I do that if I have **the name of the form** only available as a **string**? I.e., I need to write some library method

```
Sub OpenAnotherInstanceOfForm(ByVal formName As String)
    Dim frm As Form ' or Object, late binding is fine for me in this case

    Set frm = ... ' <-- What goes here?
    frm.Visible = True

    ... ' Persist the object reference, so that frm stays open. I know how to do that.
End Sub
```

Here is what I have already tried:

- `Set frm = CreateObject("Form_" & formName)` - Run time error 429
- `Set frm = Eval("New Form_" & formName)` - Run time error 2482

Comment: Previously: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10917896/how-to-create-a-new-form-instance-using-the-name-of-the-form-as-a-string

Comment: @TimWilliams: Thanks, I did not see the duplicate! Ah, too bad it's not possible. Closing my question as a dupe.

Comment: Don't. I have a draft...

Comment: @MathieuGuindon: Ah, ok, then I'll wait.

Comment: Question though: I'm not very familiar with Access - would `Forms("formName")` yield a reference to the default instance if the form isn't loaded or opened?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon: No, that yields a run-time error.

Comment: Ugh. Gets tricky. I'll delete my answer then, I'm guessing `Select Case` was obvious, and without a default instance of the form class then the factory / `CallByName` approach doesn't hold water.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon: No problem, thank you for your efforts!