# Is There a Getproperty or Equivalent Function?

Tags: vb.net, vba, getproperty

I would like to know if something like this pseudo code:

`myVar = "functionName" 

call someObject.(myVar evaluation)`

which would then be equivalent to:

`call someObject.functionName`

is possible in VB. I know this is done in some other languages using a GetProperty method.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744216/how-do-i-assign-a-value-to-a-property-where-the-property-name-is-supplied-at-runt/1744555#1744555

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the [CallByName](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/186143) method to accomplish this. There is also an Eval function in VB/VBA.

Here's the code for that in VB.Net:

```
CallByName(YourClassName, "variableName", CallType.SET, valueToSet)
```

You can even read property using it's string-name:

```
someVariable = CallByName(YourClassName, "variableName", CallType.GET)
```